# Using fork of Reactjs in a different project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, reactjs

I'm having trouble determining how to reference my react fork in a project I want to use it in while a PR request I made is being reviewed. Since the root `package.json` is `react-tools`, I can't use the npm github references. I also haven't had success making a local path reference to any of the react subdirectories I've tried.

How can i use my version of react in my separate project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here turned out to be `npm link`

In `./project_dir`, run `npm link /path/to/react/repo/build/npm-react`

This creates a sym link from the `react` npm module to the project `node_modules/react` directory.